# Back transforming the intercept of double log normal distribution

Tags: data-transformation, lognormal-distribution, back-transformation

I apologise if this is a duplicate, i couldn't find a thread that seem to be talking about the same thing.

I have a dataset with a bunch of duration of varying lengths in seconds, i log-transformed the dataset and binned them in to bins with width of 0.5 log-units. using this data, i plotted the following bar graph. [image]

Next, I obtained the maximum likelihood estimation of the of my data set

p = 0.856

$\mu_1$ = 0.831

$\mu_2$ = 5.903

$\sigma_1$ = 1.036

$\sigma_2$ = 0.703

using these parameters, i drew the double gaussian according to

$y = p(\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})) +  (1-p)(\frac{1}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2})  )$

2 distributions will cross at $(x_c,y_c)$ when

$p(\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(x_c-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})) =  (1-p)(\frac{1}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(x_c-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}))$

$x_c$ = 3.25

**I wish to back transform $x_c$ into seconds**

my understanding is that $exp(x_c)$ will not give me an accurate estimation. Because if, for example, i wish to back transform the $\mu$, $exp(\mu)$ gives me the geometric mean instead of the arithmetic mean. a more precise way is to use the Johnson back-transformation which is $exp(\mu +0.5\sigma^2)$. Thus, my question is, **how do i back transform $x_c$ to get an accurate estimation in seconds?**

Comment: Your expression is not a "transform" of $x,$ because for any given value of $y$ there may be two and as many as four corresponding values of $x.$  This expression is that of the *density* of a mixture of Normals, which is rarely (if ever) used for transformation (and has nothing to do with what is usually understood to be a "lognormal" distribution).  One has to suppose you are confused about what is happening, but without having any context, we have little guidance for setting you straight.  Could you tell us the statistical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am currently trying to apply the same method as detailed in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003347298910223). in short, after log transformation and binning the data into bins with width of 0.5 log units, the probability density of my data show up as a double normal distribution. i wish to obtain the point where the 2 distributions cross

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  If I understand it correctly, it means the references to log transformation, binning, and even back-transformation are just distractors and that your question is how to solve the stated equation for $x$ for the given values of the parameters.  After taking logarithms of both sides you will obtain a quadratic equation: applying the quadratic formula does the trick.  You can therefore anticipate obtaining *two* solutions for the crossing (which will occur whenever $\sigma_1\ne\sigma_2.$  Pick the one lying between the means $\mu_i.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am aware of how to obtain $x$ which is 3.25 log units. My confusion is that since this data has been log transformed, $x$ = 3.25 log units is not exactly of what i am trying to find. I need to back transform $x$ into the original scale. And that is where is am stuck

Comment: The "back-transform" of the logarithm is, by definition, the exponential function.

Comment: my understanding is that it is more complex than that, for example, if i wish to back transform $\mu$, $exp(\mu)$ gives me the geometric mean instead of the arithmetic mean. The paper i am trying to follow used $exp(\mu +0.5 \sigma^2)$. along this vein, i'm guessing $exp(x)$ will not be an accurate estimation

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to estimate, then!  Up to and including this point you have provided information indicating only that you wanted to find the place at which two normal density functions cross.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the data set is originally in seconds, it was log transformed and binned into bins of 0.5 log units with the $y$ axis being probability density. This gives a double normal distribution. the 2 normals cross at point $(x_c,y_c)$. solving for $x_c$ gives me $x_c$ = 3.25 log units and I wish to find the value of $x_c$ in seconds. But my consideration is that since $exp(\mu)$ is not a accurate estimation of the mean in seconds, i cannot expect $exp(x_c)$ to be an accurate estimation of the $x_c$ in seconds

Comment: It is becoming apparent from your comments that the question as asked has little to do with what you are trying to accomplish.  May I suggest you edit it to describe your data, explain your objective, and then state what you need?

Comment: i have edited to add more details to the question. May i ask which areas of my question was unclear?

Comment: Most of it has been cleared up now, except for one critical part: the statistical problem you have!  You have described a procedure to obtain a logarithm, namely $x_c.$  It's a mathematical fact that its inverse transform is $\exp(x_c).$ However, *what is this value intended to represent?*  What statistical question is it trying to answer?  For instance, if you are trying to find an interior anti-mode of the distribution of the original data, the answer will be different.

Comment: The point where the 2 gaussian cross ($x_c$) represents a threshold. Since the original values are duration lengths, $x_c$ represents a threshold duration i can use to define whether a particular duration belong to either the 1st or 2nd distribution, E.g. lets say the back-transformed $x_c$ is 3 seconds, all data with duration < 3 seconds belong to the 1st distribution which those >3 seconds belong to the 2nd distribution. i am really just trying to find the threshold

Comment: OK, we're nearly there.  The problem is that there are at least two valid definitions of "threshold" in this context: the place where the densities of the *logarithms* cross and the place where the densities of the *original data* cross.  Which is the one that is relevant to your problem?  It sounds like the latter, but that isn't completely clear because the analysis was performed in terms of the logarithms.  This suggests we need a better understanding of the meaning of a crossing of density functions in this problem.

Comment: Looking at the plot, it seems doubtful that the best mixture model is from two normal distributions as the curve and histogram are not well matched. Have you tried a find distribution program, e.g., [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html)  followed by a [find distribution parameters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html) program?

Comment: Regarding your question, the back transformation of a sum into the native coordinate system is a product; $e^{A+B}=(e^A) (e^B)$, such that the geometric mean does not seem inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, turns out the problem is that i implemented the equation wrongly in my code. otherwise, the paper i was following used $exp(x)$. Terribly sorry for taking up your times